# Database path variable in Java Firebase Admin SDK ValueEventListener

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, wildcard

In the Java SDK, I would like to have value of var in the example below.

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = db.getReference("/foo/{var}/bar");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   ... here I want the value of var
  }
};
```

Writing to /foo/foobar/bar fires the event, with the correct snapshot. I would like ot access the value "foobar".

In the cloud functions SDK, I can do something like this:

```
functions.database.ref('/foo/{var}/bar').onWrite(e=>{
  var value = e.params['var']; // would be foobar in above path
}
```

Is this at all possible in the Java SDK? Asking for the parent key gives me only "{var}" not the actual value.

Comment: this `var value = e.params['var'];` would give you var.. so if {var} in your database is foobar it will give foobar

Comment: @peter If I write data to /foo/horse/bar, then in the onWrite trigger, e.params['var'] would be horse.

Comment: yes thats write like what I said if {var} is foobar it will give you foobar

Comment: Ok. But that is not an answer to the question. The question is, how can I do this in the Java SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for such wildcard paths is unique to the Cloud Functions SDK for Firebase. The Firebase Database SDKs don't support wildcards in paths.

So your code:

```
ref = db.getReference("/foo/{var}/bar");
```

This code will (as far as I know at least) only match that exact path `/foo/{var}/bar`. If you see this matching all paths under `/foo`, can you tell me the exact SDK you are using as I'd like to give it a spin?

Comment: It seems I was too quick in the assumption that the snapshot being correct. onDataChange is executed once upon adding, and the value is null, as what I thought would be a variable does not exist. I should have tested further with value changes in the database to confirm my assumption. I guess I was focusing too much on getting the key in the path. It's a shame wildcards are unique to Cloud Functions.